# How to define a variable as Type List<<>f_AnonymousType1<string,string>>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I see in a watch window that the following LINQ statement

```
model.UserLanguages = (from u in db.Users
                    join l in db.Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
                    select new {UserName = u.LastName, Language = l.Name}).ToList();
```

returns a variable of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f_AnonymousType1<string,string>>`.

I need to assign it to the property of a model class, so I need to be able to explicitly name its type. Something like this:

```
public List<{string, string}> UserLanguages { get; set; }
```

But since that is not correct syntax, of course, I get an error.

When I set it to:

```
public List<object> UserLanguages { get; set; }
```

I get the error:

```
The type "System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string UserName, string Language>>" cannot be converted to "System.Collections.Generic.List<object>"
```

Comment: You can´t do that, an anonymous class is just - well, anonymous - it doesn´t have a name which you can use anywhere. Instead just *create* a named class and then create an instance of it: `Select new MyClass { UserName = ..., Language = ... }`. Then you get you have a `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: What does one have to do to take results from a LINQ statement with anonymous output and put it in a model property? Can't tuples be used here somehow?

Comment: To use a Tuple instead, you can try `select new (UserName: u.LastName, Language: l.Name)` (C# 7 syntax). Then have your property typed as `IEnumerable<ValueTuple<string, string>>`

Comment: @haim770 And how to assign that to a property?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, Same as it is now, using `model.UserLanguages`

Comment: @haim770 why IEnumerable<ValueTuple<string, string>>? Just do this IEnumerable<(string userName,string language)>

Comment: @MistyK, You're right. I missed that part in the new Tuple syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can´t do that, an anonymous class is just - well, anonymous - it doesn´t have a name which you can use anywhere. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type.

Instead just create a *named class* and then create an instance of it

```
class MyClass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Now create instances of this class from your query:

```
model.UserLanguages = (from u in db.Users
                join l in db.Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
                select new MyClass {UserName = u.LastName, Language = l.Name}).ToList();
```

where `UserLanguages` is a `List<MyClass>`. This makes it clear to any user of your API that an instance within that last has a `UserName` and a `Language`.

Another way would without a class would be to have a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

```
model.UserLanguages = (from u in db.Users
                join l in db.Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
                select new MyClass {UserName = u.LastName, Language = l.Name}).ToDictionary(x => x.UserName, x => x.LastName);
```

But that seems less intuitive, as a user has to know that the `Key` applies to a `UserName`, while the `Value` is a `Language`.

Comment: Creating an explicit class as you suggested here worked perfectly, of course. I've been programming for years in PHP and wasn't thinking in the strong-typing paradigm: everything much more explicit: it makes sense since you also have the rich object in the razor view. Very nice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `dynamic` object aka `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`

Declare the model property as `public List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> UserLanguages { get; set; }`

here's psuedo code:

```
void Main()
{
    Test db = new Test();
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.UserLanguages = (from u in db.Users
                    join l in db.Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
                    select new {UserName = u.LastName, Language = l.Name})
                    .Select(x=> {
                        dynamic expando = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
                        expando.UserName = x.UserName;
                        expando.Language = x.Language;
                        return (System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)expando;
                    })
                    .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)model.UserLanguages[0]).UserName);
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Users = new List<User>(){
            new User(){
                LanguageId = 1,
                LastName = "Hello"
            }
        };
        Languages = new List<Language>(){
            new Language(){
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test"
            }
        };
    }
    public List<User> Users{get;set;}
    public List<Language> Languages{get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int LanguageId{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}

}

public class Language
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class MyModel
{
    public List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> UserLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That however will also allow `myModel.UserLanguages[0].UndefinedProperty` which will cause a runtime-error.

Comment: need to do typecasting e.g. `((dynamic)model.UserLanguages[0]).UserName`, check updated answer

Comment: That´s not my point. I mean the instances within that list can be *anything*. How should a user of that API know how instances within the list look like? You can´t prevent that a user whrongly types `Username` with lower-n for example. This then causes an exception at runtime, whereas you could have *compile-time*-safety if you´d have a strong type in the first place.